# Bachelor's degree transcript (Marks Sheet) and Certificate Watermarking

Tags: watermarking

Earlier, I  mistakenly wrote that question in academia.stackexchange.com. Now pasting the same question after someone told me that its relevant to this forum.

I am from Pakistan and considering to move to a country of good academic standards to pursue a masters degree. I came across a fellow Pakistani who is in USA for some time now and also manages a facebook group about students who are in USA and who want to move to there for further studies. I also asked him to guide me according to my profile as to what are my chances with my current profile and he asked to email him my transcript.

So what should be the proper way to send the documents to anyone? Will watermarking be enough? What details should I hide?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! To get a good answer, I think you will need to be more clear what it is you are trying to protect yourself from. Are you worried he will use your documents and claim that they are his own? That he will abuse your personal information in some way? If so, what personal information and how?

Comment: Just to be clear, watermarking is when you put a visible mark on a document (like [this](http://www.a-pdf.com/watermark/examples/text-sample.gif)), thereby rendering it unusable for some purpose, but do not actually hide any information. It is not the same as putting a black box over information you don't want others to get.

Comment: I want him to see all the information on that: my name, photo, the degree title, the courses I took, what score I got in each of the courses, what grade I got overall, CGPA, year of issuance, credit hours etc. I just want to get rid of the possibility of any misuse or identity theft that may occur by my emailing him the document.

Answer (score 1):

Watermarking your resume or transcript doesn't protect you from serious threats. I'm not familiar with the the content of transcripts from Pakistan but in the USA they do not contain government IDs which would be one of the pieces need to full assume someone's identity.

If I were you, I would reach out to universities I want to attend and work with them directly. Universities have advisers that can give you the information you need and give you feedback on your transcript. I advise you to send your transcript directly to a university over a random facebook group admin.